# Flutter wrong position of text in textfield after changing height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

According to my design I have a `TextField` with 30pt of height.

Here's how I am trying to do that:

```
Container(
            height: 30,
            child: new TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                  hintText: "Search",
                  fillColor: Colors.lightGreen),
            )),
```

And here's the result:

[image: Search]

How can I align hint and text vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set contentPadding to EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0) in InputDecoration. This will remove the default horizontal padding for the Text:

```
Container(
    height: 35,
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(5.0),
            ),
          ),
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
          hintText: "Search",
          fillColor: Colors.lightGreen),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]